# Llenar un select desde mongoDB con Express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

La idea es llenar un select con datos traidos desde la Base de Datos Mongo, para lo cual en la busqueda traigo solo el dato de las mesas, evito traer la fecha y el id que aparecen en la Base de datos

```
router.get('/ingresos/mesas', async (req, res) => {    
  const consultaMesa = await Mesa.find({},{mesa:1, _id:0});
  const arreglo = [];             
    for (const llena in consultaMesa) {                
      arreglo.push(consultaMesa[llena]);
    } 
    console.log(arreglo);
    res.render('ingresos/llenamesas', {arreglo});                 
});
```

En el html llenamesas

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="mesas1">Mesa</label>
    <select id="mesas1" class="form-control">
      <option>[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]</option>
        <script>
            var array =[{{arreglo}}];                   

                for(var i in array){ 
                document.getElementById("mesas1").innerHTML += "<option   value='"+array[i]+"'>"+array[i]+"</option>"; 
                }
        </script>
    </select>
</div>
```

en el terminal de visual studio code logro ver que trae el listado de mesas

```
[ { mesa: '1' }, { mesa: '2' }, { mesa: '3' }, { mesa: '4' } ]
```

Pero en la consola de Google Crome aparece

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'

y me especifica

```
var array =[{ mesa: &#x27;1&#x27; },{ mesa: &#x27;2&#x27; },{ mesa: &#x27;3&#x27; },{ mesa:    &#x27;4&#x27; }];
```

No se si es que los datos del array estan llegando al select de un modo que nos los entiende

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: que template engine estas usando para renderizar el html?

Comment: gracias por responder uso handlebars